# Sed issue!! i tried to trigger this command cat test.txt | gf xss | sed ‘s/=.*/=/’ | sed ‘s/URL: //’ | tee testxss.txt

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, web-applications, arch-linux

i tried to trigger this command

```bash
cat test.txt | gf xss | sed ‘s/=.*/=/’ | sed ‘s/URL: //’ | tee testxss.txt
```

but getting error as sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `' sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command:` '

please help resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are using "pretty" quotes instead of proper quotes.

Use `'` instead of `‘` and `’`

Comment: after making above suggested changes getting below error sed: invalid option -- '/'

Comment: Please update your question with the exact command you used.